# Проблема при вызове alertdialog в android

Tags: android, java

В активити:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    super.onCreateDialog(id);
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(1);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog; 
        case DIALOG_ALERT:
             mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
             mAlertDialog.setMessage(R.string.internet);  
         mAlertDialog.setTitle(R.string.error);  
         mAlertDialog.setCancelable(true);  
         mAlertDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.ok,  
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                    finish();
            }  
            });  
         mAlertDialog.show();
        default:
            return null;
    }
```

В `AsyncTask` качаю файлы запускаю прогресс бар. Пытаюсь вызвать `alertdialog`, вылетает в крит

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
       showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT); <- тут
    }
```

Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

В `onCreateDialog()` не нужно вызывать `show()`, нужно просто вернуть созданный диалог. Если проблему это не решит - покажите какое исключение выбрасывается.

**Upd:** почему проблема не проявляется с прогрессом: там вы возвращаете диалог, а в случае с алертом - возвращаете `null` из-за отсутствия `break/return`. Решение не меняется, но на будущее: ставьте `break` в case-блоках, если в них нет return'ов. [Подробнее про switch/case/break можно прочитать по данной ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402074/android-menu-does-not-work-properly/7402120#7402120).